# Using PySDM To Change Permissions

Tags: 11.10, permissions, external-hdd, pysdm

So I'm trying to understand how to change permissions on an external drive. It seems like only 1 user can connect via the Samba share.

I've read some things about installing PySDM, so beginners (like myself) don't have to edit the `/etc/fstab`.

Would this be something I need to change the permissions to allow other users to access the external drive?

Comment: Are you trying to set up more samba users? If so, then PySDM is not the tool. Try `gadmin-samba` instead.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the permissions on the external drive set for all samba users. Only one user can currently access the drive. Thought this might be a route to go with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add samba users with the `smbpasswd` command:

```
sudo smbpasswd samba_username
```

That should ask you for your admin password, and then for the samba_user password.

You can also install and use `gadmin-samba`, [check out the howto](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/12/25/configure-samba-with-gadmin-samba/).